# I want to access a member variable of an object

Tags: c++

When making a class how would I differentiate the two different class variables. I want to add elements in two vectors together and get a new vector with the sum of the two different numbers. In the code below when making an instance of a class I have access to it's vector but what about the one in parameters? number_blocks being the vector variable in the class BigInt

```
    BigInt BigInt::add(const BigInt& number){
      int flag = 0;
      int carry = 0;
      int sum = 0;
      const int LIMIT = 9;
      int size = number.length();
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        sum = number_blocks[i]// + number_blocks_number[i];
        if(flag == 1){
          sum = sum + carry;
          flag = 0;
        }
        if(sum > LIMIT){
          carry = sum / 10;
          sum = sum % 10;
          flag = 1;
        }
        number_blocks.push_back(sum);
      }


  return BigInt();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your questions does not make sense.  Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry I'm a relatively new programmer. What I mean is say I have declared Bigint a = 10. and BigInt b = 1 BigInt stores it in a vector called number_blocks. I want to be able to add the vector to another BigInt number_blocks so that it returns 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do `number.length()`

```
number.number_blocks[i]
```

BTW: you have to push the carry at the end (if nonzero).

Note: please ask specific questions. "I want to access a member variable of an object". show a one liner example. nobody cares about the rest.

Comment: ah thanks I'm not used to this website

Answer (score 0):

Issues that I see with your implementation of `BigInt::add`:

1. You are returning an default instance of `BigInt` in the line:

   ```
   return BigInt();
   ```

   It makes sense to me that you would return a `BigInt` that is the result of adding two `BigInt`s.
2. You are not taking into account the `BigInt`s of varying length. For example, adding `187` with `85`.
3. You are ignoring the last carry. If you add `9` and `9`, you need to carry the `1`.
4. The logic for computing the sum and the carry can be simplified to:

   ```
   sum = this->number_blocks[i] + number.number_blocks[i] + carry;
   carry = sum / 10;
   sum = sum % 10;
   ```

   You don't the variables `flag` and `LIMIT`.

Here's an implementation that addresses those issues.

```
BigInt BigInt::add(const BigInt& number){
   int carry = 0;
   int sum = 0;

   // Compute the minimum number of digits from both the numbers.
   size_t size1 = this->length();
   size_t size2 = number.length();
   size_t size = size1 < size2 ? size1 : size2;

   BigInt ret;

   // Process the digits that are in both the the first number and the
   // second number.
   for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      sum = this->number_blocks[i] + number.number_blocks[i] + carry;
      carry = sum / 10;
      sum = sum % 10;
      ret.number_blocks.push_back(sum);
   }

   // If the first number has more digits than the second, deal with the
   // remaining digits from the first number.
   if ( size1 > size )
   {
      for(size_t i = size; i < size1; i++)
      {
         sum = this->number_blocks[i] + carry;
         carry = sum / 10;
         sum = sum % 10;
         ret.number_blocks.push_back(sum);
      }
   }

   // If the second number has more digits than the first, deal with the
   // remaining digits from the second number.
   else if ( size2 > size )
   {
      for(size_t i = size; i < size2; i++)
      {
         sum = number.number_blocks[i] + carry;
         carry = sum / 10;
         sum = sum % 10;
         ret.number_blocks.push_back(sum);
      }
   }

   // Deal with the last carry.
   if ( carry > 0 )
   {
      ret.number_blocks.push_back(carry);
   }

   return ret;
}
```